# Under what condition will Excel think an add-in has a serious issue?

Tags: c#, excel-addins

I have an Excel XLL AddIn

It uses a modal window on two ribbon buttons click handler. 
When one modal window is on, I right click on the button on the bottom tool bar. Restart Excel, everything is fine my addin has no issue. 
When the other modal window is on, I right click on the botton on the bottom tool bar. Restart Excel,  look, Excel complains "Excel experienced a serious problem with the 'xxxx' add-in. If you have seen this message mutiple times you should disable this add-in and check to see if an update is available. Do you want to disable this add-in?"

So I wonder under what condition exactly Excel will think an add-in has a series problem?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant to Excel, but I've seen this same message for Outlook if an add-in throws an unhandled exception.

Comment: Thanks. I think it is related ot office. but not sure what condition triggers this